# Asterisk: how to get current sip.conf settings?

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip

I'm not sure if sip general parameter (such as `rtptimeout`) is set. There is no mention of it in `/etc/asterisk/sip.conf`. But may be it is set somewhere else (in include files, for example). How do I check current active value of such parameter in runtime (maybe using CLI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
[root@pro-sip ~]# asterisk -rx "sip show settings"|grep rtp -i
  Direct RTP setup:       No
  IP ToS RTP audio:       CS0
  IP ToS RTP video:       CS0
  IP ToS RTP text:        CS0
  802.1p CoS RTP audio:   5
  802.1p CoS RTP video:   6
  802.1p CoS RTP text:    5
  Symmetric RTP:          No
  RTP Keepalive:          5 
  RTP Timeout:            0 (Disabled)
  RTP Hold Timeout:       0 (Disabled)
```

Or this

```
grep -i rtp /etc/asterisk/*
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks!